# Nginx will not reroute me correctly

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have problems getting my nginx routing problem fixed when using some Docker container that should be reouted by a nginx server

I have opened port 80 for the nginx container and 3 other docker containers running on 8080, 8081, and 8082.

each of those can be accessed by calling "http://localhost:8080..81..82" respecively

when i run the following docker-compose-yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1-alpine
    ports:
      - "9999:3000"
    depends_on:
      - kbh-app-config
      - kbh-mail-services
      - kbh-apex-services
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    restart: always

  kbh-app-config:
    build:
      context: quarkus_app_config
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.jvm-temurin
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - app-config-volume:/app-config
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    restart: always

  kbh-mail-services:
    build:
      context: quarkus_mail_services
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.jvm-temurin
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      JAVA_ENABLE_DEBUG: 'true'
    volumes:
      - app-config-volume:/app-config
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    restart: always
  kbh-apex-services:
    build:
      context: quarkus_apex_services
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.jvm-temurin
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    volumes:
      - app-config-volume:/app-config
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    restart: always
  mongo-db:
    image: mongo:4.4.5
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-volume:/data/db
    restart: always

volumes:
  app-config-volume:
  mongo-volume:
```

and the nginx.config

```
upstream kbh-app-config {
  server kbh-app-config:8080;
}

upstream kbh-mail-services {
  server kbh-mail-services:8081;
}

upstream kbh-apex-services {
  server kbh-apex-services:8082;
}

server {
  listen 3000;

  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";



  location / {
    proxy_pass http://kbh-apex-services/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /app-config {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
    proxy_pass http://kbh-app-config/app-config;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /mail-services {
    proxy_pass http://kbh-mail-services/mail-services;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /apex-services {
    proxy_pass http://kbh-apex-services;
  }

}
```

When I hit "http://localhost:9999", I would expect to be rereouted to nginx "location /" which in turn should call the docker container "kbh-apex-services" running on port 8082

When I hit "http://localhost:9999" I am getting the NGNIX log message instead

```
kbhapp-nginx-1              | 2023/09/08 06:01:37 [error] 29#29: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.5:8082/", host: "localhost:9999"
```

the port 8082 seems right, but the server?

This bugs me already for some time, has anyone a good proposal maybe!?

Thank you!

Cheers,
Martin